# Split string into n parts, separated by dashes

Tags: java, string

I want to split a string s into n parts, separated by dashes. This is the function:

```
public String answer (String s, int n){}
```

For example, this should happen:

```
Example test:    ('2-4A0r7-4k', 4) 
expect 24A0-R74K 

Example test:    ('2-4A0r7-4k', 3) 
expect 24-A0R-74K
```

I did this but it gives the wrong answer:

```
String[] arr = s.split("-", k+1);
s = Arrays.toString(arr);
return s;
```

It splits starting from the end.

Comment: It is unclear to why 4 and 3 would produce those results. Please explain the algorithm involved for splitting like this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel what is unclear? It splits starting from the end.

Comment: And that is something that you should describe explicitly in your question: don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String split(String str, int n) {
    final Function<String, String> reverse = s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
    String[] parts = reverse.apply(str.replaceAll("-", "")).split("(?<=\\G.{" + n + "})");
    return IntStream.range(0, parts.length).mapToObj(i -> reverse.apply(parts[parts.length - i - 1])).collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
}
```